# Receive path from file Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin

I want an option where I search a file in the folders on my phone and it returns me in my string this way **"/data/data/Fotos/imagem.png"**

how to do this by xamarin Forms, both for android and ios

Comment: You might want to try this component: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/pclstorage

Answer (score 0):

using PCLStorage;

IFolder folder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;

IFile file = folder.GetFileAsync()

string path = file.Path;